# Issues when displaying ASCII Art in command prompt

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:menu

color 0b
ping localhost - n 5 >nul
type C:\Users\Suzettec\Desktop\textgamemenuscreen.txt
ping localhost - n 10 >nul
cls
goto menu2
:menu2
echo OOOOO OOOO OO  OO OOOOO
echo   O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main>Game
echo   O   OOOO OO  OO   O  
echo.
echo.
echo [1] Start
echo [2] Instructions 
echo [3] Exit
set/p type="C:\Main>Game= "
if type == 1 then goto TextGameMAINLEVEL
if type == 2 then goto Inst
if type == 3 then goto Exit
goto menu2
```

This doesn't work.

I want it too show the "type" and then switch to menu2. The TEXT `C:\Main>Game` ASCII Art don't work. It outputs:

```
O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main
```

instead of

```
O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main>Game
```

Comment: "Something like" is not very precise.

Comment: I dont remember what it says instead of "TEXT C:\Main>Game"

Comment: Why can't you run it again?

Comment: I added the exact incorrect text and the required text for you. Had you done it yourself, you might have found the problem yourself, and possibly even the solution ;)

Comment: Im using another computer, and i dont have permission to create .bat files :/

Comment: `Im using another computer, and i dont have permission to create .bat files :/` vs. `But the first :menu section with the type command does not output the ASCII Art i made.`? Something's fishy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
echo   O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main>Game
```

is equivalent to

```
echo   O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main > Game
```

the relevant part being `> Game` which directs the output of the preceding command, i.e. the text *"`O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main`"* into a textfile named *"Game"*.

You need to escape the `>` character using `^`:

```
echo   O   O0     OO     O   C:\Main^>Game
```

---

Further info: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: Don't forget to delete your files named "Game" again :)

Comment: But the first :menu section with the type command does not output the ASCII Art i made.

Comment: I asked my adminstrator for permission :)

Comment: What about "C:\Users\Suzettec\Desktop\textgamemenuscreen.txt"? Does that folder exist on the machine you are on right now? Why was that not a problem? Could be you did not tell the truth all the time and are now misusing StackOverflow as a CodeForMeForFree site?

Comment: In any case. If I was too insinuating, I am sorry. In any case, your new question should be posted in a new Question. This "Thread" is done by now, because your question was answered and you are supposed to accept an answer :)

Comment: Im not misusing the site. The folder and file exist, because i made it.

Comment: @user3493606: Okay, beg your pardon, though I did not say that you misuse the site (was trying to give a new member a usage advice; sorry if the sound was too harsh and the smily didn't help)